# JQuery single and double quotes problems

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to insert a tag into the page. but inside that a tag, it has both single quote and double quote, so i try put that part into an variable Var content. Can someone tell me why this var content is not showing on onclick after code runs?

```
var content = "javascript:window.open('https://ds.contactatonce.com/ds/p10819departmentselector.htm?OriginationUrl='+encodeURIComponent(location.href),'','resizable=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,height=520,width=450');return false;"



$('<a style ="float: left; margin-top: 20px" href="#" onclick=" + content + " ><img onerror="this.height=0;this.width=0;" border="0" alt="Click to instant message  Representative Now!" title="" src="https://dm5.contactatonce.com/getagentstatusimage.aspx?MerchantId=270075&ProviderId=10819&PlacementId=10"></a>').insertBefore('.header-contact-phone');
```

it was like this before but it keep showing errors

```
$('<a style ="float: left; margin-top: 20px" href="#" onclick="javascript:window.open('https://ds.contactatonce.com/ds/p10819departmentselector.htm?OriginationUrl='+encodeURIComponent(location.href),'','resizable=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,height=520,width=450');return false;" ><img onerror="this.height=0;this.width=0;" border="0" alt="Click to instant message !" title="Click to instant message a Now!" src="https://dm5.contactatonce.com/getagentstatusimage.aspx?MerchantId=270075&ProviderId=10819&PlacementId=10"></a>').insertBefore('.header-contact-phone');
```

Comment: var content = "javascript:window.open('https://ds.contactatonce.com/ds/p10819departmentselector.htm?OriginationUrl='+encodeURIComponent(location.href),'','resizable=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,height=520,width=450');return false;"

$('').insertBefore('.header-contact-phone');

Comment: Please move all code into the question itself, rather than adding it as a comment.

Comment: I did that before, but is causing a error because inside the double quotes it has single quote,

Comment: $('<a style ="float: left; margin-top: 20px" href="#" onclick="javascript:window.open('https://ds.contactatonce.com/ds/p10819departmentselector.htm?OriginationUrl='+encodeURIComponent(location.href),'','resizable=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,height=520,width=450');return false;" ><img onerror="this.height=0;this.width=0;" border="0" alt="Click to instant message !" title="Click to instant message a Now!" src="https://dm5.contactatonce.com/getagentstatusimage.aspx?MerchantId=270075&ProviderId=10819&PlacementId=10"></a>').insertBefore('.header-contact-phone');

Comment: ^ --- this doesn't help. Please edit the question...

Comment: Why don't you just put all the logic into a function that is called when you click the "a" element? Why bother with trying to put some kind of eval'd string? That looks like bad news to me.

Answer (score 2):

Use the escape character \ before the quotes 
like this:

`var y = "We are the so-called \"Vikings\" from the north.";`

see this links:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_strings_escape

Comment: Among all the beautiful documentation online it's so sad to see such low quality links here.